# Group data by Value Range SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used "`CASE WHEN [TRONG LUONG]< 10000 THEN '<10KG' ELSE '>10KG' END AS "TRONGLUONG"` " in my query and here is my result.

NGAY GUI    ---MA TINH PHAT---  TRONGLUONG---   SANLUONG

01/03/2022  ---     BGG    ---      <10KG   ---5534

01/03/2022  ---     BGG     ---     >10KG   --- 263

It's ok but how can I do to get this result? (like Pivot Table in Excel)

NGAY GUI--- MA TINH PHAT    ----    SANLUONG<10kg --- SANLUONG<10kg

01/03/2022  ---     BGG       ---      5534     ---      263

01/03/2022   ---    BKN     ---    706      ---      34

Comment: Look at `PIVOT` in SQL Server

Comment: Slightly misleading to say ">10KG" when you mean ">=10KG". I know we say things like "over the age of 21" but there's still potential for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select pvt.*
from
(
    select d.dtDate,d.category,d.sanloung, 
    case when d.weight<10000 then 'Under 10kg' else 'Over 10kg' end as TRONGLUONG
    from tblDummy as d
) as q
pivot
( 
    max(q.sanloung) for q.TRONGLUONG in ([Under 10kg],[over 10kg])
) 
as pvt
```

[image]